# Windows equivalent of Linux JQ tool command

Tags: windows, jq

I have a linux jq command

```
 jq -r '."FOO-BAR"[] | .foo+ " " + .bar[]'
```

What would be equivalent of this in Windows shell syntax? I have tried this and I get a compile error

```
 jq -r "."FOO-BAR"[] | .foo+ " " + .bar[]"
```

Answer (score 3):

The double-quotes in the original (i.e., the interior double-quotes) must be escaped, as discussed in the [Windows section of the jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#windows).

Thus your example would become:

```
jq -r ".\"FOO-BAR\"[] | .foo+ \" \" + .bar[]"
```